# Передача переменной из js в php методом ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно передать переменную из JavaScript используя Ajax и получить её в PHP? Необходимо также, чтобы при этом осуществлялся переход на необходимый роут, например, mysite/contacts

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: может хоть покажете свой код или по крайней мере скажете, на нативном js или на какой нибудь библиотеке вам нужно это сделать.
А вообще вот: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--В шапке страницы или перед следующим скриптом подключаете jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<!--в подвале ставите скрипт-->
<script>
$('body').on('click tap', '#your-button', function (e) {
// по щелчку по любому элементу с id "your-button"

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        // методом get ajax'ом отправляем

        data: {'data_name_to_send': 'data_value_to_send'},
        // переменную data_name_to_send со значением data_value_to_send

        dataType: "html",
        // если какие-то данные должны вернуться, то в формате html

        success: function (data) {

            // в случае успешной отправки переходим на адрес "корень сайта"
            window.location = '/';
        }
    });
});
```